# How to pass a custom enum to a function in powershell

Tags: powershell, enums, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-cmdlet

When defining a function, how can you reference a custom enum?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   namespace JB
   {
       public enum InternetZones
       {
          Computer
          ,LocalIntranet
          ,TrustedSites
          ,Internet
          ,RestrictedSites
       }
   }
"@ -Language CSharpVersion3

function Get-InternetZoneLogonMode
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]   
        [JB.InterfaceZones]$zone
    )
    [string]$regpath = ("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\{0}" -f [int]$zone)
    $regpath
    #...
    #Get-PropertyValue 
}

Get-InternetZoneLogonMode -zone [JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites
```

But this gives the error:

```
Get-ZoneLogonMode : Unable to find type [JB.InterfaceZones]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At line:29 char:1
+ Get-ZoneLogonMode -zone [JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (JB.InterfaceZones:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

NB: I'm aware I could use `ValidateSet` for similar functionality; however that has the disadvantage of only having a name value; as opposed to allowing me to program using friendly names which are then mapped to ints in the background (I could write code for that; but enum seems more appropriate if possible).

I'm using Powershell v4, but ideally I'd like a PowerShell v2 compatible solution as most users are on that version by default.

**Update**

I've corrected the typo (thanks PetSerAl; well spotted).
`[JB.InterfaceZones]$zone` now changed to `[JB.InternetZones]$zone`.
Now I'm seeing error:

```
Get-InternetZoneLogonMode : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'zone'. Cannot convert value "[JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites" to type 
"JB.InternetZones". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name [JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites to a valid enumerator name.  Specify one of the following 
enumerator names and try again: Computer, LocalIntranet, TrustedSites, Internet, RestrictedSites"
At line:80 char:33
+ Get-InternetZoneLogonMode -zone [JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-InternetZoneLogonMode], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-InternetZoneLogonMode
```

Comment: Your function declares `$zone` as `[JB.InterfaceZones]` not as `[JB.InternetZones]`.

Comment: Doh! Thanks - though still getting an error (updating post)

Comment: just call it in this way: `Get-InternetZoneLogonMode -zone TrustedSites`

Comment: Perfect thanks both! (I'd originally tried the easy way; but hadn't since correcting the typo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISE gave this one away to me but your attempted syntax was not completely incorrect. I was able to do this and get it to work.

```
Get-InternetZoneLogonMode -Zone ([JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites)
```

Again, If you look at the highlighting you will see how I came to that conclusion.

[image: syntax highlighting]

Answer (score 0):

Per comments by PetSerAl & CB:

- Corrected typo in function definition

  - from `[JB.InterfaceZones]$zone`
  - to `[JB.InternetZones]$zone`
- Changed function call

  - from `Get-InternetZoneLogonMode -zone [JB.InternetZones]::TrustedSites`
  - to `Get-InternetZoneLogonMode -zone TrustedSites`